# How to use one popup box to display arbitrary number of information respectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

So I currently have a section for projects. This section will have an image of the project and when you click on it, a popup box will appear with more information about that project.

## Problem

How can I use one popup box for arbitrary number of projects. So whenever you click on any project, the same popup box (with css) will pop up with information about that project respectively.

For example:

[Project Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y2hW.jpg)

[When user clicks on any project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9MBI.jpg)

As you can see, that popup box with the information is the same information displayed on any project that is clicked.

The image that is displayed, I have the following html:

```html
<!-- ========= li ========= -->
<li>
  <div class="item-img">
    <img alt="Ink Transition Effect" src="img/HQCLogo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="item-info light-bg" style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241)">
    <a href="http://www.hqcglobal.com"><em>HQCGlobal</em></a>  <i class="date">March 12, 2015</i>
  </div>
  <div class="feed" id="feed1">
    <div class="heart" id="like1" rel="like"></div>
    <div class="likeCount" id="LikeCount1"></div>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- ========= li ========= -->
```

The code for the popup box is the following:

```html
<div class="java-popup" role="alert">
  <div class="java-popup-container">
    <a href="#0" class="java-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
    <div class="left-box">
      <img src="img/HQCLogo.svg" width="750px" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-description-box">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br />
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-popup -->
```

In order to trigger the click even to open the popup box, Ive used js:

```js
  // Open popup box
  $('.item-img').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.java-popup').addClass('is-visible');
  });
  //close popup
  $('.java-popup').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.java-popup-close') || $(event.target).is(
      '.java-popup')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });
```

So the big question is, how can I use my popup box div to display different information according to the project clicked?

Thanks
Naseeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.java-popup` div is just a normal HTML div. It is displayed as a pop-up using `position:fixed/absolute` to allow arbitrary positioning on screen, and `z-index` to place it overtop of other DOM elements.

You can inject new HTML content into the sub-divs using standard js/jQuery methods, such as `.html()`, `.append()`, `.text()` etc

```js
$('#pop1').click(function(){
   $('#overlay').show();
   $('.java-popup').fadeIn();
});

$('#pop2').click(function(){
   $('.left-box').html('<img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />');
   $('.right-description-box').html('Any kind of HTML can go in here, divs, images, styled p tags, anything.');
   $('#overlay').show();
   $('.java-popup').fadeIn();
});

$('.java-popup-close').click(function(){
   $('#overlay').fadeOut();
   $('.java-popup').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
*{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
#overlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:black;opacity:0.7;z-index:98;display:none;}
.java-popup{display:none;position:fixed;top:20px;left:50px;width:450px;height:250px;background:white;overflow:none;z-index:99;}

.java-popup-container{overflow:hidden;}
  .java-popup-close{position:absolute;right:20px;top:0;z-index:999;}
  .left-box{float:left;width:60px;height:100%;}
  .right-description-box{float:left;width:390px;height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="java-popup" role="alert">
  <div class="java-popup-container">
    <a href="#0" class="java-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
    <div class="left-box">
      <img src="img/HQCLogo.svg" width="750px" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-description-box">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br />
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-popup -->
<button id="pop1">Show popup</button>
<button id="pop2">Change Info in Popup</button>
```

Comment: I see what you did. I am mostly interested in your Js code. Although this is one way of doing it, it is too redundant because I would need to copy the same code again and again, but just change the image src using DOM injection, which is bad idea. So basically, is there a way of creating one codeblock of Js to show() and hide()?

Comment: Purpose of my answer was to demonstrate we are talking about a normal HTML div, and content injection. No magic. Go with any suitable method you can devise for swapping out/in content into that div structure, and then showing it. You can definitely turn that into a function with inputs for image and content. Your modal div structure will be static, so *have at it, and bonne chance* (as my betters would say)

Answer (score 0):

i dont have 50 rep, or i would comment this, but you might be better off using a modal. bootstrap has an easy to use modal system, and w3schools has a tutorial on them. 
Link to w3schools bootstrap modal tutorial:http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Hi there, I know I can use a model. But I'd like to learn how to implement it from scratch, to better my understanding.

Comment: fair enough. i dont have any information to help you on that front, im somewhat entry level :/

Comment: No problem. Thanks for getting back to me